# Delete and Insert concurrently on DB2 table

Tags: java, db2

I have deleting 50000 records at a time in one table at the same time. some other user from another application trying to insert data in that same table, but current delete transaction locked the table until finish delete operation.

Insert operation asked to wait till delete operation complete.
I want to insert the records in the same table while performing delete from Java technologies.

can anybody help on this?

Comment: If you are using DB2, why did you tag your question with MySQL and Microsoft SQL Server tags?

Comment: I thought that the same issue occurs with the all databases, if we can achieve this with any other database means kindly let me know.

Comment: You need to use a smaller unit of work size and commit more frequently. For example try halving the size of the delete , then successfively halving that number until you get the concurrency you want.   If the OTHER application is using Repeatable-Read isolation level or Read-Stability isolation level then you will need very small batch size (commit after every 100 deletes for example) and also you might need to throttle the deletes by adding a configurable delay time in the loop that commits the deletes.

Comment: I'd say the problem is not related to Java at all. It's more of a database problem, i.e. when and how the data gets locked (isolation level etc.). It also depends on your data and table setup, i.e. if the inserts wouldn't result in duplicate entries even if the delete had not happened (i.e. the data is completely independent) then running both in parallel shouldn't be a problem. If duplicates could happen then you'd have to somehow order the deletes and insert but what makes sense also depends on your data, table setup etc.

Comment: _Probably_, the database thinks that the new `INSERT`ed row would satisfy whatever condition the `DELETE` was run with.  Which might be none, if you're executing a bare `DELETE`.  Do you have some disambiguating column, like an insert timestamp?  Could we see the statements and some sample data?